# Forcing docker-compose to use current version of image

Tags: docker, docker-compose

*This might look like a duplicate issue, but the solutions in other posts are either outdated or it just doesn't work for me. Please see my question before marking it s duplicate.*

I have a docker-compose script which is using an image in from a repostitory. When running `docker-compose up` first time, it correctly downloads the current image. Second time it doesn't. I found one should call `docker-compose pull`, but this seem not do anything:

```
# docker-compose pull
Pulling webapp ...
```

After a few minutes, I `ctrl-c` the execution as I had no idea whether anything is happening.

Another issue with `docker-compose pull` is that it doesn't accept `-f` parameter to provide path to the `docker-compose.yml` meaning I cannot run it from a script running in a different directory.

Then I run `docker pull my-image` and it correctly started redownloading the image. The problem is that I don't want to worry about the name `my-image`, because the contents of the `docker-compose.yml` might change.

Would it maybe help to remove the tags from the local repository?

I really miss some kind of `--force-pull` feature of `docker-compose up`.

Comment: Why you want to pull images again...it's internally implemented in Docker if sha256 for the concerned image is changed it will automatically pull newer image from docker-registry during service creation or build phase ?

Comment: No it doesn't pull the current image. If the image is updated in the repository, it still uses the old one.

Comment: Have you tried `docker-compose up --force-recreate` ?